# python smypy/matplotlib input output with symbolic equations

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

This program is intended to graph a shape (after the I/O issue is resolved).

I used a template from a program I wrote previously to make this but I seem to be missing something here. I have tried going through the program and troubleshooting but have not been able to figure it out. The print statements are purely my efforts at troubleshooting.

The intended functionality is to supply a numpy array to the function and it will return the appropriate X and Y values also in terms of arrays.

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np

def rose_func(thetarange):
     _theta = thetarange
     r, x, y, theta = sy.symbols('r, x, y, theta')

     rose_eq = ((((x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** sy.Rational(7 / 2)) + 6 * (
        3 * (x ** 5 * y + x * y ** 5) - 10 * x ** 3 * y ** 3)) / (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 3) - 1

     sub_rose = rose_eq.subs([(x, r * sy.cos(thetarange)),
                         (y, r * sy.sin(thetarange))])

     print("subbed eq:", sub_rose)
     print("subbed eq:", sy.latex(sub_rose))
     print()

     simp_rose = sy.simplify(sub_rose)
     print("simplified eq:", simp_rose)
     print("simplified eq:", sy.latex(simp_rose))
     print()

     solv_rose = sy.solve(simp_rose, r)
     print("Solved eq:", solv_rose)
     print("Solved eq:", sy.latex(solv_rose))
     print()

     X = sy.lambdify('r', solv_rose*(int(sy.cos(_theta))), "numpy")  #may need to multiply by r(theta) or theta again

     Y = sy.lambdify('r', solv_rose*(int(sy.sin(_theta))), "numpy")  #may need to multiply by r(theta) or theta again

     return X(_theta), Y(_theta)

 thetavar = np.linspace(-3.14 * 2, 3.14 * 2, 250)

 rose_func(thetavar)
```

The working 'template' I based this program off of:

```
    def mac_ser(x, N):
    _x = x
    n, z, x = sy.symbols('n, z, x')
    my_equation = sy.summation((z ** n / sy.factorial(n)), (n, 0, N))
    sub_eq = my_equation.subs([(z, -x ** 2)])
    mac_lam = (sy.lambdify('x', sub_eq, "numpy"))
    print("Mac test", mac_lam)
    print("Type is:", type(mac_lam(_x)))
    return (mac_lam(_x))

    x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 1000)
    test = mac_ser(x, 2)
```

Here are my current errors:

````
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\cache.py", line 94, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\cache.py", line 94, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2/scratches/scratch_21.py", line 51, in <module>
    rose_func(thetavar)
  File "C:/Users/.../Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2/scratches/scratch_21.py", line 15, in rose_func
    sub_rose = rose_eq.subs([(x, r * sy.cos(thetarange)),
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\cache.py", line 96, in wrapper
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 465, in __new__
    result = super().__new__(cls, *args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\cache.py", line 96, in wrapper
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py", line 280, in __new__
    evaluated = cls.eval(*args)
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\functions\elementary\trigonometric.py", line 570, in eval
    if arg.could_extract_minus_sign():
AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign'```
````

Comment: You can't subs in a numpy array until you've lambdified the expression.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, I added the function I based this one off of where I used subs before the lambdify.

Comment: It should be `cos(theta)` not `cos(thetarange)`.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, thank you, I made that correction. I have been looking at this for days and I have been swapping things around a ton trying to figure it out.

I am still getting the errors listed in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a common occurrence that people struggle to use numpy and sympy together. Please keep in mind that numpy does not know that sympy exists and that sympy does not like numpy based inputs. Unless you are an expert in both, please don't try to use them interchangeably. Please see every third question on stack overflow with the tag `sympy` to see similar problems and gain understanding.

I have found 3 main problems with your code:

1. sympy functions liek `sy.sin` don't take in numpy arrays. You must give it either pure python objects like ints or sympy objects.
2. `sy.solve` returns 2 solutions in your case. You need to pick one of them by doing something like `sy.solve(...)[0]` to get the first solution.
3. `sy.lambdify` I don't think is comfortable with a string as its first argument. Use the symbols that you created in the start. It is also a function of `theta` and not of `r`.

Here are the corrections and I have clearly split the sympy parts and the numpy parts.

```py
import numpy as np

def generate_rose_func():
    """
    Generates the lambdifed expressions.
    No numpy allowed in this function.
    No sympy allowed out of this function.
    """
    import sympy as sy
    r, x, y, theta = sy.symbols('r, x, y, theta')

    rose_eq = ((((x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** sy.Rational(7 / 2)) + 6 * (
        3 * (x ** 5 * y + x * y ** 5) - 10 * x ** 3 * y ** 3)) / (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 3) - 1

    sub_rose = rose_eq.subs([(x, r * sy.cos(theta)),
                             (y, r * sy.sin(theta))])

    print("subbed eq:", sub_rose)
    print("subbed eq:", sy.latex(sub_rose))
    print()

    simp_rose = sy.simplify(sub_rose)
    print("simplified eq:", simp_rose)
    print("simplified eq:", sy.latex(simp_rose))
    print()

    solv_rose = sy.solve(simp_rose, r)[0]  # solve returns 2 solutions in this case. Pick the first one
    print("Solved eq:", solv_rose)
    print("Solved eq:", sy.latex(solv_rose))
    print()

    X = sy.lambdify(theta, solv_rose * sy.cos(theta), "numpy")  # may need to multiply by r(theta) or theta again
    Y = sy.lambdify(theta, solv_rose * sy.sin(theta), "numpy")  # may need to multiply by r(theta) or theta again
    return X, Y

def rose_func(thetarange):
    X, Y = generate_rose_func()
    return X(thetarange), Y(thetarange)

thetavar = np.linspace(-3.14 * 2, 3.14 * 2, 250)
print(rose_func(thetavar))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its definitely working and I am able to graph it now.

I completely misunderstoon how and what I was supposed to pass for #1